# Payfort iOS SDK: Textfields for card details hidden

Tags: ios, swift, payment-gateway, payfort

I have integrated Payfort iOS SDK. I have provided my custom Xib for card details and it is working fine on the Sandbox mode, but all the textfields are hidden in the production mode.

I have checked all the changes such as -> Production url for requests, SHA keyphrases, merchant id etc.
I am getting success when I am calling the payfort sdk with request parameteres. But when payfort open the view, it is blank.
Instances of the views are there, but they all are hidden.

Edit -

I have set a custom Xib, it is working with custom Xib.

Comment: There was some problem with the xib file. I replaced it and it works now.

Comment: Hi, you've any sample code? I've customise this process in android and tested it in sandbox mode. it's working fine but when I used arebic language then transition is not working proper. If possible then share you sample code

Comment: What do you mean by transition is not proper?

Comment: if i used arabic language in android then translation is not woking proper (transition* =translation)

Comment: Can you share some screenshots?

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/0gELRVLy naresh see this image some content are in english